# pass a prop from a v-link in vue.js with vue-router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have a prototype that I'm using vue.js, and vue-router in.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)


let router = new VueRouter

import App from './App.vue'
import Details from './Details.vue'
import Pics from './Pics.vue'

router.map({
  '/details':{
    name: 'details',
    component: Details
  },
  '/pictures':{
    name: 'pics',
    component: Pics
  }
})

router.start(App, '#app')
```

App.vue contains my `router-view` mounting point. App also contains a list of `Location` components based on the location data stored in my shared state:

App.vue:

```
<script>
    import state from './state.js'
    import Location from './Location.vue'

    module.exports = {
      components: {Location},
      data: () => {
        return {
          name: 'app',
          locations: state.locations
        }
      }
    }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="app-container">

    <h2 class="heading">Locations</h2>
    <div class="body">
      <div class="column">
        <location v-for="location in locations" :location="location"></location>      
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <router-view></router-view>      
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>
```

state.js:

```
exports.locations = [
  { name: 'Home', address: '123 main st', pics: [{src: '/images/123.png'}]},
  { name: 'Work', address: '555 Avenue st', pics: [{src: '/images/lol.jpg'}, {src: '/images/wrkn.jpg'}]},
  { name: 'Some Landmark', address: '42 E West st', pics: [{src: '/images/coolpic.jpg'}, {src: '/images/qwerty.jpg'}]}
]
```

The `Location.vue` component holds the `v-links` that I'm using to trigger the router:

Location.vue:

```
<script>
    module.exports = {
      props:['location'],
      data: () => {
        return {name: 'location'}
      }
    }
</script>

<template>
  <div class="location-container">
    <h3>{{location.name}}</h3>
    <a v-link="{name: 'pics'}">Pics</a>
    <a v-link="{name: 'details'}">Details</a>
  </div>
</template>
```

What I would like would be to pass in the given location state instance as a prop to the component called by the router (either `Details.vue` or `Pics.vue`) when the particular location's `v-link` is clicked.

The problem I'm having is that while I know the docs say you can do this, they don't explain how to do this and I've not been able to figure out how. I tried binding location to the `router-view` in `App.vue`:

```
<router-view :location="location"></router-view>
```

And binding it to a placeholder within `router-view`:

```
<router-view>
    <details :location="location"></location>
</router-view>
```

Neither of which work.

What's the proper way of doing this?

I have a WebpackBin demo of the problem here: http://www.webpackbin.com/4kDRbt28W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those intersted: We figured it out on gitter.

Solution is to not pass the object at all, but pass it's ID as a param in the URL (e.g. `/details/1827`), then get the object for that ID from the store in the component.

Advantages: URLs can be directly navigated to from external sources and application state will be fine.